# ASP.net web API GET method called twice

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mono

I am trying to compile and run ASP.net web api project in mono. On windows this projects works fine but in mono the GET method is called twice. This happens only with GET method. The project has authentication requirement, so if any end point is hit without authentication the returned error response is also twice. What can be the issue?

Comment: A little code would help. Can you add the controller and the client code?

Comment: I am sending the request through Postman plugin in chrome, there is no client code.
We have 2 projects one for controllers and one for models. This issue was happening with our code so I simply downloaded the code example by microsoft (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and tried running it. When I add this as a new project in our current solution everything works but when I add the controller to our controller project and try to run same issue occurs.
Are there any global project specific settings that could be causing this?

Comment: Very strange. I am quite sure this is not related to a project setting. Did you try to put a break point on the method and trace the flow of control? May be that sheds some light on the issue.

Comment: Please put your last comment as *an answer*..and mark it.  This will help future people...and also remove this from the "not answered' filtered on SOF.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to narrow down the issue. This was happening because WebApiConfig.cs was getting registered twice